# Android Card Layout Design

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

I am very new in android and need to develop the card layout. I dont have any idea how can i make it in layout design?. Can you please suggest me how we can make it?. If any sample code available please share it.

[image]

Comment: so far i tried and developed self learning of android basic only. how to make a gird and list view layout and action oriented and etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear, as you don't have any mockups or examples to show what your "card layout" would look like.

My suggestion is to make a `RelativeLayout` in your `res/layouts` folder. An example would look like this

[image]

Here's what the code would look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Blue"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="MY CARD"
    android:textColor="@color/White"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since you didn't specify what your card's dimensions would be I picked a `layout_width` of the relative layout to match the screen via `match_parent` and I set the height of the relative layout to be `layout_height=200dp`. I picked 200 density pixels as a choice you can pick whatever you like...

To add a background just add an `ImageView` and pick a background from your drawables folder via `android:src="@drawable/...`

**Update:**

Alternatively you can now use the `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` in your layout to make a `CardView`. This is a much solution to the one posted above.

Comment: layout design given above. Same like we have to make it and develop...

Comment: Use a `RelativeLayout` which contains an `ImageView` and two `Imagebutton`s. Then put this `RelativeLayout` inside another layout (let's use a `FrameLayout`) and then use it in an activity via `setContentView(R.layout.MyFrameLayout)

Comment: how we can make it left swipe and right swipe from framelayout?. do you have any idea?.